# Create Json multiple Array String In android

Tags: android, json

I am try to create Json String containing multiple `JsonArray` and `JsonObject`. I want to create Json string as format shown below:

```
[
{
    "CustomerId": -1,
    "PoolGuyId": 117,
    "FilterChanges": [
        {
            "FilterChangeId": -1,
            "CustomerId": -1,
            "Reminders": [
                {
                    "ReminderId": -1,
                    "FilterChangeId": -1,
                    "CustomerId": -1
                },
                {
                    "ReminderId": -2,
                    "FilterChangeId": -1,
                    "CustomerId": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "FilterChangeId": -2,
            "CustomerId": -1,
            "Reminders": [
                {
                    "ReminderId": -3,
                    "FilterChangeId": -1,
                    "CustomerId": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "IsDeleted": false
}
]
```

i was try lot of reference but still my string not create.
help me

I am getting value from database. In sqlite database there are 3 tables named as customerDetails, JobHistory, Reminder. In these tables multiple values are stored.

```
try {
        customerDetailsTable = new CustomerDetailsTable(con);
        customerDetailsTable.open();
        arrayListCustomer = customerDetailsTable.getAllContacts();
        customerDetailsTable.close();
        JSONObject objCust = null;
        JSONArray jsonArrayCust = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListCustomer.size(); i++) {
            customerDetailsSetGet = arrayListCustomer.get(i);
            objCust = new JSONObject();
            try {
                objCust.put("CustomerId", customerDetailsSetGet.getCustomerID());
                objCust.put("PoolGuyId", customerDetailsSetGet.getPoolGuyId());
               } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
            ArrayList<JobHistorySetGet> arrayListjobHistory = new ArrayList<>();
            jobHistoryTable = new JobHistoryTable(con);
            jobHistoryTable.open();
            arrayListjobHistory = jobHistoryTable.getJobsAsPerCustId(customerDetailsSetGet.getCustomerID());
            jobHistoryTable.close();
            JSONObject objJobHis = null;
            JSONArray jsonArrayJob = new JSONArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayListjobHistory.size(); j++) {
                jobHistorySetGet = arrayListjobHistory.get(j);
                objJobHis = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    objJobHis.put("FilterChangeId", jobHistorySetGet.getFilterChangeId());
                    objJobHis.put("CustomerId", jobHistorySetGet.getCustomerId());
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
                ArrayList<ReminderSetGet> arrayListReminder = new ArrayList<>();
                reminderTable = new ReminderTable(con);
                reminderTable.open();
                arrayListReminder = reminderTable.getReminderAsPerJobID(jobHistorySetGet.getId());
                reminderTable.close();
                JSONArray jsonArrayReminder = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject objReminder = null;
                for (int k = 0; k < arrayListReminder.size(); k++) {
                    reminderSetGet = arrayListReminder.get(k);
                    objReminder = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        Log.d("Anuj", "9");
                        objReminder.put("ReminderId", reminderSetGet.getReminderId());
                        objReminder.put("FilterChangeId", reminderSetGet.getFilterChangeId());
                        objReminder.put("CustomerId", reminderSetGet.getCustomerId());
                        jsonArrayReminder.put(objReminder);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
                objJobHis.put("Reminders", jsonArrayJob.toString());
                jsonArrayJob.put(objJobHis);
            }

            objCust.putOpt("FilterChanges", jsonArrayJob.toString());
            jsonArrayCust.put(objCust);
         }
        JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();
        finalobject.put("Final", jsonArrayCust.toString());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my requirement is in hierarchical order means There may be multiple customer table, and in each customer table there will be multiple JOBs and In each jobs ,there will be multiple Reminder

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried

Comment: the posted json is not correct.please look at json

Comment: JSON format is not correct ..please validate your JSON format first...use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: refer this link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html

Comment: Kat-Hat and Vishwa now Json format r8 check it

Comment: my requirement is in hierarchical order means There may be multiple customer table, and in each customer table there will be multiple JOBs and In each jobs ,there will be multiple Reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one..this one is for making json string based on your json.

```
try {
        customerDetailsTable = new CustomerDetailsTable(con);
        customerDetailsTable.open();
        arrayListCustomer = customerDetailsTable.getAllContacts();
        customerDetailsTable.close();
        JSONObject objCust = null;
        JSONArray jsonArrayCust = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListCustomer.size(); i++) {
            customerDetailsSetGet = arrayListCustomer.get(i);
            objCust = new JSONObject();
            try {
                objCust.put("CustomerId", customerDetailsSetGet.getCustomerID());
                objCust.put("PoolGuyId", customerDetailsSetGet.getPoolGuyId());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
            ArrayList<JobHistorySetGet> arrayListjobHistory = new ArrayList<>();
            jobHistoryTable = new JobHistoryTable(con);
            jobHistoryTable.open();
            arrayListjobHistory = jobHistoryTable.getJobsAsPerCustId(customerDetailsSetGet.getCustomerID());
            jobHistoryTable.close();
            JSONObject objJobHis = null;
            JSONArray jsonArrayJob = new JSONArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayListjobHistory.size(); j++) {
                jobHistorySetGet = arrayListjobHistory.get(j);
                objJobHis = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    objJobHis.put("FilterChangeId", jobHistorySetGet.getFilterChangeId());
                    objJobHis.put("CustomerId", jobHistorySetGet.getCustomerId());
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
                ArrayList<ReminderSetGet> arrayListReminder = new ArrayList<>();
                reminderTable = new ReminderTable(con);
                reminderTable.open();
                arrayListReminder = reminderTable.getReminderAsPerJobID(jobHistorySetGet.getId());
                reminderTable.close();
                JSONArray jsonArrayReminder = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject objReminder = null;
                for (int k = 0; k < arrayListReminder.size(); k++) {
                    reminderSetGet = arrayListReminder.get(k);
                    objReminder = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        Log.d("Anuj", "9");
                        objReminder.put("ReminderId", reminderSetGet.getReminderId());
                        objReminder.put("FilterChangeId", reminderSetGet.getFilterChangeId());
                        objReminder.put("CustomerId", reminderSetGet.getCustomerId());
                        jsonArrayReminder.put(objReminder);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
                objJobHis.put("Reminders",jsonArrayReminder);
                jsonArrayJob.put(objJobHis);
            }

            objCust.putOpt("FilterChanges", jsonArrayJob);
            jsonArrayCust.put(objCust);
        }
        JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();
        finalobject.put("Final", jsonArrayCust);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer Vishwa! 

But my requirement is in hierarchical order means

There may be multiple customer table, and in each customer table there will be multiple JOBs and In each jobs ,there will be multiple Reminder

like Customer1
{ 
Jobs1 
   {
   Reminder1, reminder2
   } 
   Jobs2
   { 
   Reminder1
   }
}
Customer2
{ 
  Jobs1 
  { 
     Reminder1, reminder2
  }
Jobs2
{
    Reminder1
 }
}